# Serving an audio file

Tags: phoenix-framework

EDIT: Got it solved a while back, see the answer below.

Related: [Great post about serving video files, the same stuff can be applied here.](https://medium.com/@miguel.coba/streaming-video-with-phoenix-31cd6c3048e#.8o3e3340l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def send_audio(conn, headers, audio) do
        audio_path = build_audio_path(audio)
        offset = get_offset(headers)
        file_size = get_file_size(audio_path)

        conn
        |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_header("content-type", audio.content_type)
        |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_header("content-range", "bytes #{offset}-#{file_size-1}/#{file_size}")
        |> Plug.Conn.send_file(206, audio_path, offset, file_size - offset)
end

def get_offset(headers) do
    case List.keyfind(headers, "range", 0) do
      {"range", "bytes=" <> start_pos} ->
        String.split(start_pos, "-") |> hd |> String.to_integer
      nil ->
        0
    end
  end
```